# Dataframe overriding entire column

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have one issue while updating excel sheet using pandas.

I have one column named `'item'` in my excel sheet and a list of some strings in python. 
I am iterating over each list item to check if list string exist in `item` column of excel sheet , If exist I am updating the string in same row under `brand_name`

Here is my code

```
for index_label, row_series in new_df.iterrows():
    for brnd in  ['brand1','brand2','brand3']:
        try:

            if brnd in  row_series['item']:
                new_df.at[index_label,'brand_name'] = brnd

            else:
                new_df.at[index_label,'brand_name'] = ''
        except:
```

Now the problem here is instead of updating for all brands . I can see data only for `brand3`  under `brand_name` column of excel and I can't see anywhere `brand1` and `brand2` in brand_name column. However I see sub-strings of `brand2` and `brand3` exist in `item` column of my excel sheet.

Please help me out why not all brands are populating in column why just the last one.

Somthing about Excel sheet.

```
item   , brand_name 

some_brand1_two_like_thi     
some_brand2_two_like_thi     
some_like_this_brand1
brand3 two_like_thi     
brand3 two like thi
```

Comment: Can you provide screenshot of excel sheet for reference?

Comment: Hi I can't share the excel but updated the question with sample

Comment: I can't distinguish between separate cells of column 1,2 and 3. Why don't you post a small screenshot on imgur and post link here?

Comment: As mentioned by @micric, you are initializing values in your dataframe in a loop, you should come ut of loop once your job is done, otherwise it will override the correct value with erroneous one, which here will be brand_1 and brand_2.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing the results of the if/else block of brand3 over the results of brand1 and brand2. Try to follow the loop that you have written:

- it uses 'brand1' and checks if 'brand1' is there. If it finds it, it will write 'brand1' in the new df.
- you go to the next step of the loop, 'brand2' will not be there and it will write the empty string in the same position, deleting 'brand1'. The same goes with 'brand3', so it's the only one you can find.

Adding break after the successful part of the if/else statement should be enough:

```
if brnd in  row_series['item']:
   new_df.at[index_label,'brand_name'] = brnd
   break
```